# KAFKA producer not working with 2 replication factor and 1 ISR, if one broker is down

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka and using SpringBoot(2.7.11) KafkaTemplate.
Below is my ProducerFactory Config:

```
  public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    LOG.info("Initializing Producer factory properties...............");
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(
        ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
        "localhost:9092,localhost:9093");
    configProps.put(
        ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(
        ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(
        ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG,
        "PF-"+String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()));
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "pp-trx-id-"+UUID.randomUUID());
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG,5000);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.METADATA_MAX_IDLE_CONFIG,5000);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG,"all");
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, true);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG,10000);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
  }
```

when any of broker goes down, Producer don't send message to Kafka and get Failed with **TimeoutException** in 10000 ms with Topic does not exist msg.

**@Note: But If I use 3 replication factor and 2 ISR then if I down 1 broker then its working fine.**

Can someone please check what could be the possible issue.

I have tried almost all properties.

Comment: i am not sure but have you tried to change ACKS_CONFIG? in the past when i got that kind of timeout was because producer was configured to not send to all brokers but also get confirmation from all of them. try, is possible, a less restrictive ack configuration.

Comment: Please attach topic configuration

Comment: What do you mean by "any broker" going down causes an error? You seem to have 3, but if there's only two replicas, then there's a broker without a replica that could go down without causing any issues